# How to use Mockito to test dependencies in MainActivity onCreate of Android

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito

I was wondering how to test dependencies in the MainActivity in Android. This is a simplified example. I want to mock `MyClass` with Mockito.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MyClass myClass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.doSomething();
    }
}
```

I have tried using Static Factory Method and I've looked into some other factory patterns. The trouble is that `MainActivity.onCreate` seems like a dead end where it is difficult to inject a mock of `MyClass`.

Is there a way to mock `MyClass` with Mockito here without using another mocking or dependency injection library? I am very happy to restructure the code as necessary.

**UPDATE** I just thought that I could use a setter. Would this be an appropriate solution? The main trouble I see is that it is creating a setter purely for the mock that is inappropriate to be used by anything else. At least, it could be package private to limit access.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MyClass myClass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setMyClass(new MyClass());
        myClass.doSomething();
    }

    void setMyClass(MyClass myClass) {
        this.myClass = myClass;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2** I've also realised that in not making `myClass` private, I can use something like `mMyActivity.myClass = mockMyClass`. Is that a good way to do this? I think `myClass` really should have been private. It also means letting the default constructor run to create `myClass` and then changing its state in a way that shouldn't normally happen.

Answer (score 1):

If you add [PowerMockito](https://github.com/jayway/powermock), you could do this with `PowerMockito.whenNew(MyClass.class)`. But you would ned to add `@PrepareForTest(MainActivity.class)` to your TestCase

Comment: I had spotted PowerMockito. I was concerned that it said that it works by modifying the bytecode. Could it cause unexpected consequences? Are there things to watch out for?

Comment: Yes, one downside would be that code coverage may not longer work as expected. If you let PowerMockito modify your class with @PrepareForTest  no coverage will be calculated with JaCoCo. For some UI classes I created a internal factory-class to preserve the coverage-data.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to [Dagger 2](http://google.github.io/dagger/).

From the first look it is not clear how to use it. But take a look to examples - https://github.com/chiuki/friendspell

Comment: Dagger was my original thought to deal with this. I was hoping that there would be a way without adding an extra layer of complexity to the app like Dagger.